# How can I run Python 3.9.1 natively on M1 Mac?

Tags: python-3.9, apple-silicon

Seems to be impossible currently with Anaconda as well as with Xcode 12. Via idle, it runs via Rosetta. There seems to be no discussion of this so either I'm quite naive or maybe this will be useful to others as well.

Python says: "As of 3.9.1, Python now fully supports building and running on macOS 11.0 (Big Sur) and on Apple Silicon Macs (based on the ARM64 architecture). A new universal build variant, universal2, is now available to natively support both ARM64 and Intel 64 in one set of executables" https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.9.html

Please help a newbie figure out how to take advantage of his recent impulse-buy.

Answer (score 26):

You can now install python 3.9.1 through multiple pathways now but the most comprehensive build environment for the full data-science suite for python at the moment (Feb 2021) on M1 ARM architecture is via miniforge.

e.g.

```
brew install --cask miniforge
conda init zsh
conda activate
conda install numpy scipy scikit-learn
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The question is about running natively, not through Rosetta translation. Running python 3.9.1 on the ARM M1 chip, Python processes are labeled 'Intel Architecture' in Activity Monitor. This seems like a compiler problem. How do I compile to run natively on the ARM chip? This happens through Anaconda as well as Xcode 12.

Comment: I'm not sure how you set it up. The [homebrew installer](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/blob/HEAD/Casks/miniforge.rb) does correctly install the ARM version of miniforge on M1 chips.

Comment: Well it works. But the problem is that you are not allowed to use Anaconda in a commercial context. :( I hope it will become possible with a regular Python installation soon, so I can use my Mac Pro at my company.

Comment: What does “not allowed to use anaconda in a commercial context” mea?

Comment: I refuse to use conda

Comment: The conda-forge offshoot from conda provides native ARM MacOS versions of miniforge and mambaforge (https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge) along with a fair assortment of packages.

Answer (score 17):

You can now install Python 3.9.4 natively on Mac M1 (Apple Silicon). I'm using pyenv to install Python 3.7, 3.8 and 3.9 all native ARM. For example, to install 3.9.4:

```
$ pyenv install 3.9.4
python-build: use openssl@1.1 from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
Downloading Python-3.9.4.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.9.4/Python-3.9.4.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.9.4...
python-build: use readline from homebrew
python-build: use zlib from xcode sdk
Installed Python-3.9.4 to /Users/squademy/.pyenv/versions/3.9.4
```

For a complete guide on install pyenv and multiple Python version, you might read this article: https://squademy.medium.com/install-python-on-macos-11-m1-apple-silicon-using-pyenv-12e0729427a9.

Comment: how stable is homebrew on arm64? ps +1 for pyenv 

Comment: Do you have your article published somewhere more accessible? That link is blocked by sign-in to Medium

Comment: Edit queue full, but I've just tested original pyenv docs and works on Mac M2.Good guides in your Medium page, just original docs are always up to date and never behind paywalls :)

Answer (score 15):

I am using python3.9.4. I installed it using homebrew only.

```
brew install python@3.9
```

Also you may want to do the following to unlink and check the version number

```
brew unlink python3
brew link python3.9
python3 --version
```

Answer (score 3):

I upgraded to 3.9.4

1. Download the Python universal installer -
   https://www.python.org/downloads/mac-osx/

Note: I still could not get sudo pip install mysqlclient to install.
I had add to

1. update homebrew - See https://brew.sh
2. Add /opt/homebrew/bin to PATH in .bash_profile (don't forget to source .bash_profile)
   or
   Add /opt/homebrew/bin to PATH in .zprofile (don't forget to source .zprofile) if using zsh

Comment: does this assume your shell is bash and not zsh? with macos's change to zsh i thought we have to update `.zprofile`, not `.bash_profile`, now.

Comment: You are correct!  I was using old scripts on bash so had to update bash_profile.  I updated the answer to include .zprofile.

Answer (score 1):

No *brew* required (except drinking the joyful one at the end of the day) -

Simply download the desired *universal2* version from [Python Releases for macOS](https://www.python.org/downloads/macos/).
(These versions will work for both Intel and Mn (eg M1, M2) Macs.)

The downloaded file is a `.pkg` file, which, as expected, you double-click to install.

The process will place some informational files and version-specific *IDLE* and *Python Launcher* apps under a version-specific folder in *Applications*. It will also install the appropriate `python` executable in the system `frameworks` folder, eg `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/Python`

Now,

- You can use a virtual environment, such as the one included in *PyCharm* or explained in [python.org's tutorial for Virtual Environments and Packages](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html), by using the appropriate framework version.
- You can use the version-specific *IDLE* app from within the *Applications* folder.
- You can run scripts, without being in *Terminal*, by either dragging/dropping them onto the *Python Launcher* app's dock icon OR associating the `.py` extension with the launcher app (which will allow you to simply double-click a script in *Finder* to run it with the launcher app).

Note that if you associate the *Launcher* app with files, and you have multiple `python` versions installed on your Mac, you might want to customize the extension for the `python` version you're using (eg, `.py3.10` instead of just `.py`). That way you can associate a specific version of the *Launcher* app with the specific version of `python` you need for the script.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid messing with sistem's python, I'd recomend to follow the [guide](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) from `pyenv` docs.

I've just tested it on my Macbook with M2 and works ok.