# How to install multiple Python versions on Mac M1

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow, virtualenv, python-venv

I already installed Python 3.9.2 as it supports ARM64 as recommended in Python.org

I created a virtual environment after that using `python3 -m venv py39`

Now I need to have another environment but with Python 3.8.8 as Tensorflow is supporting 3.8 only.
How could I create another virtual environment with Python 3.8 while maintaining the other 3.9 env.
In case of asking me to use `conda`, Does conda support Mac M1 ARM64 as it doesn't according to my search

I found same question asked many times but for windows and answers are very old like:
[Use different Python version with virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv) 11 Years ago

Comment: From the docs it appears that full official support of Apple M1 started with 3.9.1: As of 3.9.1, Python now fully supports building and running on macOS 11.0 (Big Sur) and on Apple Silicon Macs (based on the ARM64 architecture). (*What's New*)

Answer (score 3):

Is there a reason you're tied to `conda`?

The reason I ask is there are easier routes to getting isolated Python environments, which might have moved a bit faster on the needed M1 migrations.

I recommend at least checking out

- [Pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv)
- [pipenv](https://pypi.org/project/pipenv/)
- [poetry](https://python-poetry.org/)

If you are tied to conda, it seems like there are some related posts: [How can I run Python 3.9.1 natively on M1 Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65559632/how-can-i-run-python-3-9-1-natively-on-m1-mac)

Comment: I assume you're saying they work on M1 chip Mac natively.  Correct?

Comment: Yes, it's Apple M1 & conda doesn't support ARM64

Comment: I didn't try conda as it does NOT support ARM64 for Mac M1

Comment: Does this question seem very close to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65534042/anaconda-and-upgrading-to-new-m1-mac

Answer (score 1):

i baught M1 and started struggling with packages and setup M1 is really fast but i was having too much issues one of the issue is python environments on intel it was very easy finally i over come to the problem with python using miniforge

here are the steps i followed

```
brew install miniforge
```

Then init zsh shell using conda

```
conda init zsh
```

and finally instantiate required python env below command will install all the dependencies

```
conda create -n .venv python=3.7.6
```

then lastly activate the environment

```
conda activate .venv
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having issues after following above solutions but it didn't work for me

```
bash-5.1$ conda activate .venv

CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
To initialize your shell, run

    $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>

Currently supported shells are:
  - bash
  - fish
  - tcsh
  - xonsh
  - zsh
  - powershell

See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.

IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init'.
```

i have zsh so i switched to bash shell and everything was started working for me

Answer (score 0):

I found out, with `pyenv` and `miniforge` it is no problem to work with conda, even with older versions like 3.8, which seemed to be a constrained on M1. With

```sh
brew update
brew install pyenv
pyenv install miniforge3-4.10
pyenv global miniforge3-4.10
conda create -n new_env python=3.8
conda activate new_env
conda install poetry
poetry new project
cd project
poetry add open3d
```

With this you can install any package and can use conda in every way you want, as far as I tested it.
Instead of peotry you can of course use `conda install {package}` in the usual way.

Comment: But we cannot install python2 (`python=2.7` for example). Did you try it?

Comment: Yes, that works for me. You need to say `python=2`. Then it installs `2.7.15`. Would be nice, if you could reproduce it.

Comment: I couldn't, it says `PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels: python=2`. :(

Comment: Btw, I think there are some differences between your "miniforge" and mine. I installed it directly from [the official github page](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge), not via `pyenv`. I've just installed miniforge via `pyenv` but my "old" one is still there. Can you tell me how to use pyenv's miniforge to crearte a new conda env?

Comment: Sure, I will update the post, to make it a bit more clear. But I am not sure how it works in the background. Could be, that it is not running as fast as other versions. But at least it works.