# Issue with Pylance and matplotlib

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have looked at these problems online but I don't seem to be able to find a good answer.

System details:

- Mac OS BigSur 11.6 on a M1 MacBook Pro
- Installed miniforge as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65559632/how-can-i-run-python-3-9-1-natively-on-m1-mac)
- Installed VSCode for Mac

I have these two following (unrelated?) problems when using jupyter notebook:

1. PyLance does not resolve imports like `numpy` etc. I see that `os` or `sys` are recognized and resolved but pretty much nothing else is. The kernel used by the jupyter notebook is the correct one. Indeed I am able to run the code with no issues but I get all these unrecognized imports.
2. I am not able to run the jupyter notebook with `%matplotlib notebook`. I can run with `%matplotlib inline`, but then I am not able to see the widgets to zoom in etc. To be more precise, if I try to plot in a cell then after it I see the following:

   - either nothing or
   - the following `<IPython.core.display.HTML object>`
     This is achieved by clicking on the symbol `</>` and changing the rendered from html to text.

I am wondering if there is some issue with my installation of python and jupyter on the M1 or it is a VSCode issue. Any suggestion on where to look into the problem(s)?